# Detect if a videoTrack is black/blank/useful

Tags: firefox, webrtc, getusermedia

There seems to be a problem in Firefox (36.0.1) where the camera chooser dialog will "remember" a wrong camera when you choose the "always allow" option.

[image: camera dialog] 
 [image]

(Sorry the pictures are in German. But the gist of it should still be clear.)

I have two cameras:

- camera A (FaceTime-Kamera (integriert))
- camera B (Logitech-Kamera)

When I select camera A and set "always allow" access, the next time `getUserMedia` **will receive the wrong input from camera B.** The resulting `videoTrack` will just be "black". I'm looking for a way to detect this behaviour in order to let the user know that the wrong camera might be selected/remembered.

Comment: You can usually check the videoTrack "readyState." If it says "live", it should be streaming.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent that works in Chrome. But `videoTrack.readyState` is always undefined in FF. (Or it needs to be called differently?)

Comment: Seems like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack does not reflect the state of current FF implementation. (`kind` and `id` is available)

Answer (score 1):

a) File a bug at bugzilla.mozilla.org! (thanks)  Probably in Firefox::Device Permissions

b) you can assign the mediastream to video_element.mozSrcObject (or for Chrome, make an ObjectURL and assign  to .src (srcObject is the 'right' way in the spec; Firefox supports both), then (once the video element is ready!) dump an image to a  and you can check it (slowly, or perhaps more quickly with WebGL) for black.

Comment: Hi @jesup filed at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1145525. Was my first time on bugzilla hopefully didn't mess it up. I'll try b) as soon as I have time. I'll get back to you then.